# Spawning user control with a button click in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I want to spawn a user control by clicking on a button. I have tried something that a user control is spawned. but when I click on the button multiple times all the previously spawned user control disappears. If you could please help me, it would be great.
Thanks...

'''

```
Public Function AddNewEntity() As System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

Controls.Add(usercontrol)
usercontrol.Top = cLeft * 25
usercontrol.Left = 100
cLeft = cLeft + 1        
Return usercontrol

End Function
```

'''

Comment: If you expect to add multiple user controls then you have to create multiple user controls. Are you doing that? Where are you creating a new instance of your user control type and how many times is that code executed? If it's in one place and you execute it once, why would you expect to have more than one control?

Comment: There is only one user control and I want to spawn it multiple times. I have created an instance of the user control globally.

Comment: If you want it multiple times than you have to create multiple instances too, not globally.

Comment: *"There is only one user control and I want to spawn it multiple times."* No. There is only one class and you want to create multiple instances of it. You instantiate a class by invoking a constructor with the `New` keyword. How many times are you doing that? If it's only once then you only have one control. Additional controls will not appear by magic. Think of it this way: if you have one friend and you add their name to a list multiple times, does that mean that you magically have multiple friends?

Comment: Everything said above it true, maybe it might help if you show us where and how your calling AddNewEntity() and the surrounds.